# update and upgrade command failed shows dpkg frontend lock (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

Command sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade (ubuntu 18.04 LTS) reflects output

````
Hit:1 http://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Get:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1,811 B]         
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/daniruiz/flat-remix/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease              
Hit:9 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x bionic InRelease                    
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:11 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                  
Get:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1,086 B]
Fetched 2,897 B in 3s (1,126 B/s)                               
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcroco3 : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.16.0) but it is not installed
 shared-mime-info : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.35.9) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
jeeva@jeeva:~$ apt --fix-broken install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?```
````

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libglib2.0-0 perl
Suggested packages:
  perl-doc libterm-readline-gnu-perl | libterm-readline-perl-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libglib2.0-0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  perl
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
123 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,372 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,344 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxau6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libapt-inst2.0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtext-charwidth-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgcrypt20:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnginx-mod-stream' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libwebp6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ca-certificates' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libstdc++6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsmartcols1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fdisk' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'util-linux' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgmp10:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libmnl0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libidn2-0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'apt-utils' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libc6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'nginx-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libaudit-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libselinux1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libx11-data' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnettle6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libp11-kit0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fontconfig-config' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'multiarch-support' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtinfo5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libbz2-1.0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'update-motd' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libext2fs2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcap-ng0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ubuntu-keyring' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblocale-gettext-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libncursesw5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpcre3:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'dpkg' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdb5.3:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libaudit1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblzma5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'e2fsprogs' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libx11-6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnginx-mod-http-image-filter' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libseccomp2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libbsd0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpam-modules-bin' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsemanage-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libss2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libblkid1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libjpeg8:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'geoip-database' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libacl1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'nginx' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'passwd' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxtables12:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'debconf-i18n' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libfdisk1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mawk' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblz4-1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtiff5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libatm1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'sed' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libattr1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libjbig0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpng16-16:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libicu65:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libexpat1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libjpeg-turbo8:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-dejavu-core' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libzstd1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgd3:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgnutls30:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtext-iconv-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgcc1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxcb1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'adduser' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'zlib1g:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libmount1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'tar' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxpm4:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libhogweed4:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsemanage1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libfontconfig1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libudev1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpam-modules:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsepol1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnginx-mod-http-geoip' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'nginx-core' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libunistring2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gcc-8-base:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxslt1.1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'apt' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'perl-base' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'openssl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnginx-mod-mail' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'sensible-utils' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcom-err2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ucf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libapt-pkg5.0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgpg-error0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpam0g:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgeoip1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'lsb-base' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtasn1-6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libuuid1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsystemd0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libffi6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gpgv' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxml2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libfreetype6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'coreutils' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxdmcp6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'iproute2' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libssl1.1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libelf1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'debconf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtext-wrapi18n-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 10703 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../perl_5.26.1-6ubuntu0.5_amd64.deb ...
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: dpkg: error: unknown option --validate-version

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/perl_5.26.1-6ubuntu0.5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: dpkg: error: unknown option --validate-version

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-0_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-0_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 triggers ci file contains unknown directive `interest-await'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/perl_5.26.1-6ubuntu0.5_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-0_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6_amd64.deb
libdvd-pkg: Package libdvdcss2-1.4.2-1 was removed, stop processing...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

update and upgrade process not completed.
I have a notification 'You have 2 broke packages on your system!
Use the "Broken" filter to locate them.

In Synaptic Package Manager searched for 'broken and got message given in image link below
[Synaptic package manager screenshot][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H2Fl.png
```

Now I am unable to fine solution! Please help..